# jQuery.eCalendar() - height of calendar

Tags: css

I wanna make this calendar height:100%.

**I tried to change css:**

```
.calendar{
   height:100% !important;
}
.c-grid{
    height:100% !important;
}
.c-event-grid{
    height:100% !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work with this css. I want it to be responsive 100%. Currently it is set with specific height.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuaowret/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspecting the fiddle, you can see that the reason for the calendar not stretching to the bottom is that it's actual parents don't.

If you add the following, it does as expected:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%
}
```

Comment: can I do it without inserting body, html. as in, can it be done with another div instead of body, html?

Comment: Your div will use the constraint of it's parents. If the parent putting the constraint is another div, then sure. Otherwise no, you'll have to remove the constraint one way or another. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

body height is 0.Try this. It works in jsfiddle.

```
body{
   height:100vh;
}
.calendar{
   height:100% !important;
}
```